SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE: Host name verification error while connecting to host
I'm writing a integration junit test case for my java application, which will calls the api and the api connects to the db and returns the data but i'm getting this "** SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  Host name verification error while connecting to host exception **" only for the first 3 times.
for testing i wrote the same method 4 times and ran the test case.first 3 will fail and the 4th one getting success.
anyone help me to resolve this issue
